# Mongo DB Version 5 Access Control With Two Read Replicas

Tags: mongodb

I have three ubuntu 20.04 servers:

1. db-master
2. db-node1
3. db-node2

I would like to know how to enable access control.
The servers work fine except when the following configuration is added to **/etc/mongod.conf** Thanks in advance:

```
$ mongo --version
    MongoDB shell version v5.0.1
$ sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf 
    security:
     keyFile: "/home/ubuntu/security.keyFile"
     authorization: enabled
$ sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running)
$ sudo systemctl restart mongod
ubuntu@db-node2:~$ sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed
```

**# mongod.conf**

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

security:
 keyFile: "/home/ubuntu/security.keyFile"
 authorization: enabled
#snmp:
```

Comment: What does the log say about the keyfile?

Comment: Thanks @Joe Checking the log helped debugging the issue. It has been fixed with the following commands:
ubuntu@db-node1:~$ sudo chown mongodb /home/ubuntu/security.keyFile
ubuntu@db-node1:~$ sudo chgrp root /home/ubuntu/security.keyFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo chown mongodb [PATH TO KEY FILE] 

ubuntu@:~$ sudo chgrp root [PATH TO KEY FILE]

ubuntu@:~$ sudo chmod 400 [PATH TO KEY FILE]
```